# What's the standard way to include external js in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, widget

I want to include a js widget in my vue application.

After trying a lot of random solutions, I came up with "my own", that is just importing it outside of vue, in the html head, then moving it with vue dom bindings to where I want it to be.

The problem is, I don't know if that is what I should be doing, in html I would just put the script tag where I want the external component to be and it would work fine.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use npm?

Comment: I imagine the standard way is to write a custom Vue component based on the script and include it the Vue way. If that component doesn't exist and what you have works fine, just keep it the way it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way is indeed to create a custom Vue component.

```
<template>
    <div></div>
</template>

<script>

    import Widget from 'widget.js'

    export default {

        name: 'my-widget',

        mounted(){

            // assume that the widget is a constructor
            // that requires an element to be bound to
            new Widget(this.$el)
        }
    }
</script>
```

And then you can import this component in another one and use it like `<my-widget></my-widget>`